# Error at creating a datetime.index with import_csv

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have to create a table with pandas with read_csv

The file looks similar to this

```
Date/time,F1 195d;speed;Avg,F2 70.4m 195d;speed;Max
2014-11-19 00:00:00,7.9694,8.9945
2014-11-19 00:10:00,7.6093,8.3518
2014-11-19 00:20:00,8.1047,8.7190
#empty line
```

The fields looks a quite weird but are separated by ,

In the example Date/time and then 2 fields more

This was my try

```
fi=open('/root to the file','r')#handle to open the file specified by fin
data=fi.readlines()
ch=[]
c=0
for line in data:
    c=c+1
    a=line.split('=')   
    if line.startswith('Date/time'):
        ch=line.split(',')
    elif line=='\n': 
        #parse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        ammo40=pd.read_csv(loc0,parse_dates=[0],sep=',',nrows=c-1,names=ch,index_col=0,header=None)
```

My code works but i got afterwards one error in the time resolution

I check both table and index and both looks weird

```
Index([u'Date/time', u'2014-11-19 00:00:00', u'2014-11-19 00:10:00',...], dtype='object')
```

While normally i get something like

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2010-01-29 00:00:00, ..., 2010-01-29 23:50:00]
Length: 144, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

I thought this could be the reason of my error but it maybe something else

If i print the table on the console i get

```
                     F1 195d;speed;Avg
Date/time                                            
Date/time            F1 195d;speed;Avg   
2014-11-19 00:00:00             7.9694
```

It seems something in the string is not properly processed then the index is not correct

Thanks

Comment: Sorry why don't you just read it in as normal without splitting? `ammo40=pd.read_csv(loc0,parse_dates=[0],index_col=0)` without looping, you can fix the header names after

Comment: This is just a small piece of the file. There are more records and afterwards more info to read about the fields. Then i think i need to use a counter in order to specify the number of records to read in the table

Answer (score 1):

You should read your csv file with the pandas built-in function:

```
import pandas as pds
df = pds.read_csv('/root_of_the_file',sep=',',header=0)
```

Then you've just to convert your string in timestamp:

```
df['my_timestamp'] = pds.to_datetime(df['Date/time'])
```